# Redirect hosts request to multiple vagrant hosts

Tags: docker, networking, vagrant, port

I have a vagrant image which runs multiple docker containers (why ? because clean seperation of dev environment).

My /etc/hosts file on the vagrant image looks like this:

```
0.0.0.0 srv1.vagrant
0.0.0.0 srv2.vagrant
0.0.0.0 srv3.vagrant
```

On the host machine:

Vagrant file: 
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "55.55.55.5"

/etc/hosts:

```
55.55.55.5 vagrant
```

Inside the vagrant image, these URLs are accessible.
However, from the host, they dont work.

Can you please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Its not a good way to fix it, but heres what i did.
On my host machine, I added the following to /etc/hosts:

```
55.55.55.5 srv1.vagrant
55.55.55.5 srv2.vagrant
55.55.55.5 srv3.vagrant
```

I tried adding *.vagrant but that didnt help redirect any traffic.